# Есть ли online БД куда можно подключить приложение для тестов?

Tags: база-данных, service, веб-служба, online

Может кто то сталкивался с таким сервисом? Хотелось бы найти онлайн БД куда можно было бы подключиться и создавать свои таблицы с чтением и записью, что бы не поднимать БД локально .

Comment: Для тестов? _Базы данных_ тестировать _не нужно_ - этим занимаются разработчики этих _СУБД_. А если вы хотите протестировать _свой репозиторий_, то замокайте его.

Comment: Они, очевидно, стоят денег, лучше уж локально поднять